# How to change the ringtone of calendar events

Tags: android, android-calendar

Apparently, Android system settings Ringtones and Notifications are completely different from the calendar -> Settings -> General Settings -> Notifications.

I figured out how to change my System Settings Notification sounds with this

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,      uri);
```

but this does not change the notification sound within the Android calendar.

What can I use to access and change the notification sounds of the calendar?